# how to carry a graphics card arround if I dont have anti static bag

Tags: esd

I want to carry a graphics card to a friends place. The Card is old and I don't have the original packaging.

I know that best way to carry it will be in an anti-static polybag and I tried hard to get one at local stores without any luck. I tried looking for them online but they come as a bunch and cost does not suit the purpose.

1. Is there any other way to safely do this?
2. I got my hands on some packaging foam from a PC which looks like conductive black foam, will wrapping the card in it will make it safe?

Comment: As long as you don't wrap the card in materials which can easily charge, like plastic(bags), bubblewrap etc. The card will not easily be damaged. A cardboard box can do the job of protecting the card. Wrap the black foam around the card so that it sits safely in the box. You can carry the card-in-box safely in a plastic bag.

Comment: cardboard/paper generates static, it is not a good medium for transporting electronics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Carefully wrap it in aluminium foil ensuring that you touch the foil and card all the time while wrapping until wrapped. Do the same when unwrapping and keep hold of the card and touch whatever target system with your other hand (to equalize any potential differences) before inserting the card.

Comment: Andy has the correct Idea, make sure that the *SHINY* side is on the *INSIDE*. the dull side has a layer of wax that is hardly conductive.

Comment: Thank you, Andy. I was inclined towards using this after reading [this forum](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/1310/Substitute+for+an+anti-static+bag)  (see KrisBlueNZ's answer). however, some people in that forum speculating that there is a risk of discharge of electrolytic capacitors as the foil is too conductive. is it true? will keeping card disconnected overnight will reduce this risk?

Comment: @tuskiomi:  The shiny side and the dull side are the same.  The only difference is in which side was pressed against the rollers. [See Wikipedia under "Properties"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_foil)

Comment: @RahulTiwari - Most capacitors will discharge in a short amount of time. A few seconds is probably fine.  Overnight is overkill.  It's really only a problem if there is a battery on the card.

Comment: thanks @Justin, I will try this out and will update the result. hopefully positive :)

Comment: @tuskiomi There is no wax on aluminum foil.  Its a myth that the sides are any different  Aluminum foil's shiny sides and dull sides are exactly the same.  The only difference is one side gets pressed against a roller and the other isnts, causing one side to to be shinier.

Answer (score 0):

If you need anti-static bags, you can just order various components that you need for any projects via Digikey, and they often ship mere handfuls of parts in larger-than-necessary anti-static bags (and they're technically free this way since your money is technically going to the parts themselves). Of course this method isn't guaranteed to get you what you need (particularly size), but it's a great way to get a few anti-static bags to keep on hand.

[Pink bubble wrap](http://www.staples.com/Staples-Anti-Static-Extra-Wide-Bubble-Wrap-24-x-30/product_657404) is a common "anti-static" shipping material, but it is kind of a low-grade "solution" since it is mainly designed to not-generate static electricity instead of preventing static discharges.

Aluminum foil/wrap is indeed the best alternative to a classic anti-static bag since it is the best way to make a Faraday Cage around your device (the operating principle of anti-static shipping materials), but be careful if you're dealing with any power sources or high-capacity capacitors since those sources can discharge electricity to other, more sensitive parts of your device via the conductive aluminum foil (anti-static bags are conductive, but also have a voltage-dependent resistance to them).